# Unable to install PHP particular version 7.0.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, deb, debian, php7

I need to install php7.0.4 but not getting this version anywhere to install it.

Is there any way to install it on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What is wrong standard [php7.0 7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0) with all security updates and fixes?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about how compatible it all is with Ubuntu, not expecting too many issues, but past versions of whatever was in Debian is retrievable on https://snapshot.debian.org. The explicit version of PHP you asked for is on https://snapshot.debian.org/package/php7.0/7.0.4-7/ (or of the latest 7.0 version see https://snapshot.debian.org/package/php7.0/7.0.32-1/). You can install the packages as instructed on the snapshot.d.o home page by specifying the date the package was uploaded. Please also be aware that you can explicityly specify the version of a package to be installed with apt-get, should there be other versions of PHP7.0 also be accessible in the repositories you specified in /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: Is PHP 7.0.32 and 7.0.4 is the same version. Could you please explain as I was asking for 7.0.4?

Comment: I edited the answer to also give the URL for 7.0.4 - somehow I had mentally upgraded to the latest 7.0 version while browsing the snapshot.debian.org pages.